# how to get send, receive byte and network bandwidth from different servers to parse with elk stack (elasticsearch logstash kibana)

Tags: logstash

Can I get the send and receive bytes from unix servers? for sample centos server. I want to get the inbound and outbound bytes then parse it to logstash so that Im able to see the histogram in kibana. Thanks in advance. I am new to here.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to make this happen.

You could run a script to gather the data on the machine, write it to a log file, use logstash-forwarder to send the logs to a centralized logstash, which then inserts into elasticsearch.

You could use some existing program to ship to logstash (collectd, etc).

Since you won't really need any of the features of logstash, you could write to elasticsearch directly via one of the client libraries (python, etc).

Unless you're limited to ELK, you could also use some "normal" network management system (snmp polling, etc).

Comment: Hi Alain Collins,

Thanks for answering my question. Can you suggest any 3rd party plugin to logstash that can collect bandwidth usage or one dedicated server. I've been using 'softflowd/netflow' as my 3rd party plugin but one is missing the 'netflow.out_bytes'. But anyway, thanks again. Now Im still reviewing collectd. Thanks.